# Run a SQL query (count) every 30 sec, and then save the output to some file

Tags: php, sql, file

I am developing a website and got a database where people can insert data (votes). I want to keep a counter in the header like "x" votes have been cast. But it is possible that there will be a lot of traffic on the website soon. Now I can do it with the query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tblvotes
```

and then display number in the header, but then every time the users changes page, it will redo the query, so I am thinking, maybe it is better to the query once every 30 sec (so much less load on the mysql server) but then I need to save the output of it to some place (this shouldn't be so hard; I can write it to a textfile?) But how can I let my website automatically every 30 sec run the query and put the number in the file. I got no SSH to the server so I can t crontab it?

If there is something you might not understand feel free to ask!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crontabs can only run every minute, at its fastest.

I think there is a better solution to this. You should make an aggregate table in which the statistical information is stored.

With a `trigger` on the votes_table, you can do 'something' every time the table receives a INSERT statement.

The aggregate table will then store the most accurate information, which you then can query to display the count.

Comment: but then it will still require the user to run a sql querry every time they switch page?(The querry won t be a count anymore but something like "select count from tbltriggercount")?

Comment: @Maximc - Yes, you'd still be forced to perform that query.  Moreover, there's a larger problem here - either your aggregate table will report incorrect results, or simply updating the table itself will become a performance bottleneck (these behaviours stem from transaction-related issues).  What you really want is some sort of in-memory solution anyways, not so much the aggregate table (with the proper indicies, a simple `COUNT()` is trivial).

Comment: Yes you'll have to perform a query each time indeed. But it would be much easier.. without aug functions like count() or sum(). E.G. `SELECT value FROM aggTable WHERE param = 'counter'` But it's still a query indeed.

Comment: You might want to look into caching the number as a txt-file in the file system.

Comment: oke I am going to create a trigger for this and this http://godefroy.me/mysql-optimisation-du-count-avec-des-triggers-a968910 (use google translate from FR to ENG) is something I found, a tip if anyone need, it basicly removes the need for the count(*) (because it is heavy for the system). Now I ll still need to find a way to automaticly create the value every 30 sec. (since cronjobs isn t enabled)

Answer (score 5):

Simplest approach: Write the result into a local textfile, check the filetime of the textfile on every request to be less than now() + 30 seconds, and if so, update the file. To update, you should lock the file. While the file is being updated, other users for whom the condition now() + 30 is met should only read the currently existing file to avoid race conditions.
Hope that helps,
Stefan

Comment: how can I see or a file is locked, and if there like 200 users at the same time on the website, are you sure it won t give a problem?

Answer (score 2):

Better solution will be using some cache mechanism (e.g. [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php)) instead of files if your server allows it.

Comment: APC lets you increment an integer: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.apc-inc.php

Answer (score 1):

If you can, you may want to look into using memcached. It allows you to set an expiry time for any data you add to it.

When you first do the query, you write the md5 of the query text associated with the result. On subsequent queries, look for the data in memcached. If it is expired, you can redo the sql query and then rewrite it to memcached.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so the first part of your question is basically about caching the result of the total votes to be included in the header of your page.  Its a very good idea - here is an idea of how to implement it...

If you can not enable a crontab (even with out SSH access you might be able to set this up using your hostings control panel), you might be able to get away with using an external 3rd party cronjob service. ([Google has many results for this](https://www.google.com/search?q=free+cronjob+service))...

Everytime your cronjob runs, you can create/update a file that simply contains some PHP arrays -

```
$fileOutput = "<"."?php\n\n";
$fileOutput .= '$'.$arrayName.'=';
$fileOutput .= var_export($yourData,true);
$fileOutput .= ";\n\n?".">";
$handle = fopen(_path_to_cache_file,'w+');
fwrite($handle,$fileOutput);
fclose($handle);
```

That will give you a PHP file that you can simply `include()` into your header markup and then you'll have access to the `$yourData` variable under the name `$arrayName`.